# Analog removeEventListener ionic 3

Tags: cordova, addeventlistener, ionic3, inappbrowser

In ionic 3 addEventListener code: `browser.addEventListener('loadstop', callback)` not working and analog is: `browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(()=>{})` But how i can reformat this code `browser.removeEventListener('loadstop', callback)` to ionic 3?

Comment: Please join my Ionic 3 chatroom - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153499/ionic-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue when trying to subscribe to push notification event and unfortunately in my case `unsubscribe()` method did not work.

The solution I found and prefer especially when I have multiple subscriptions in one page and I want to unsubscribe from them when I leave the page, is the following:

Import the RxJs operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile';
```

Define a variable, say `liveSubscription: boolean = true;` in your component.

Then subscribe like this:

```
browser.on('loadstop')
.takeWhile(() => this.liveSubscription)
.subscribe(() => {})
```

When you want to unsubscribe, simply set  `this.liveSubscription = false;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
const subs:Subscription = browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(()=>{})
subs.unsubscribe()
```